# How to handle consent frames on websites with selenium in Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

How to find child iframes on a webDriver object?

When attempting to access sites through Selenium, I will often encounter consent frames , asking if the site can use cookies.
I want to click "ok" or "agree" on these frames, and continue, but finding the controls is problematic, as they are in child frames which I cannot see.

I'm using the code below, but it cannot find the element, as it doesn't find the frame passive_signin

```
//wait for site to load
WebDriverWait wait1 = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
wait1.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.className("passive_signin")));
//switch to the new frame
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.className("passive_signin")));
//allow controls on the frame to load
WebDriverWait wait2 = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
wait2.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"text\"]")));

//agree to cookies, closing the frame
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"text\"]")).click();
```

Comment: what is the url?

Comment: I'm using it on youtube -> www.youtube.com

Comment: the button agree is not in frame..

Comment: If you haven't had a cookie for youtube set on your machine, you'll get a consent form popped up when you visit www.youtube.com.  on this popup is the "I Agree" button which needs to be pressed

Comment: With implicit wait (10 sec) this works just fine: `driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[(@class='style-scope ytd-button-renderer style-primary size-default') and (@id='text')]")).get(1).click();` Be aware there are more elements with `ID=text`, you have to specify which one you want to click. In my example I'm using xpath for both the blue buttons and click the second one.

Comment: Thanks pburgu - that solves my (current) problem!   Is there a way however to generalise this - by looking for objects (iframes etc) attached to the webdriver object?

Comment: Inspect more websites how the consent bar is displaying. Some similarities you will find but not enought to make it general. Iterating will jut slow down your tests. Better to make a method for every tested domain.

Answer (score 0):

Answered by pburgr

With implicit wait (10 sec) this works just fine:

`driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[(@class='style-scope ytd-button-renderer style-primary size-default') and (@id='text')]")).get(1).click();`

Be aware there are more elements with ID=text, you have to specify which one you want to click. In my example I'm using xpath for both the blue buttons and click the second one. –
pburgr